# How to access localhost from different network computer using wamp?

Tags: html, apache, xampp, localhost, wampserver

I done the port forwarding on my iball router with my ipv4 address and i also change the httpd.conf file to allow request from all external connection.

```
  <Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
     AllowOverride all
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
     Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

But still i can't access my index.html file with my public ip address.

Is there any other step by step process with wamp server and router port forwarding technique?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to your localhost from another computer if you are not in the same network.

The thing you can do is to copy this directory : x:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.1.3x/data/

And you put it in the same place on the other computer. Just restart your WAMP services.

You should be able to access to your datas in localhost :)

Comment: So,Is there any other method for converting laptop or desktop into server so that different network users can access my web page or services?